Apache2: Syntax error when enable virtualhost for reverse proxy
Trying to configure Apache2 as Reverse Proxy:
At etc/apache2/sites-available I have the x.conf with this detail:
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName x.com
        ServerAlias x.com
        ServerAdmin root@x.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8069/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8069/
        <Location />
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
        </Location>
    </VirtualHost>


a2ensite x.conf 
systemctl reload apache2

FAILED
    systemctl status apache2.service

x.com systemd\[1\]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
x.com systemd\[1\]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
x.com systemd\[1\]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
x.com systemd\[1\]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server...
x.com apachectl\[7889\]: **AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/x.conf:**
x.com apachectl\[7889\]: Invalid command '\\xff\\xfe\<', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
x.com apachectl\[7886\]: Action 'graceful' failed.
x.com apachectl\[7886\]: The Apache error log may have more information.
x.com systemd\[1\]: apache2.service: Control process exited, status=1/FAILURE
x.com systemd\[1\]: Reload failed for The Apache HTTP Server.
lines 1-21/21 (END)


journalctl -xeu apache2.service

A reload job for unit apache2.service has begun execution.
The job identifier is 1776.
Jun 26 09:23:14 example.com apachectl[7889]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/Apache2Proxy.conf:
Jun 26 09:23:14 x.com apachectl[7889]: Invalid command '\xff\xfe<', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Jun 26 09:23:14 x.com apachectl[7886]: Action 'graceful' failed.
Jun 26 09:23:14 x.com apachectl[7886]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 26 09:23:14 x.com systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, status=1/FAILURE
Subject: Unit process exited
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
An ExecReload= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.
The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jun 26 09:23:14 example.com systemd[1]: Reload failed for The Apache HTTP Server.
Subject: A reload job for unit apache2.service has finished
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
A reload job for unit apache2.service has finished.
The job identifier is 1776 and the job result is failed.
lines 674-696/696 (END)
Summary:
Trying to configure Apache2 as Reverse Proxy
At etc/apache2/sites-available I include the x.conf
When trying to enable the VirtualHost site and restart Apache2 to enable reload the Apache2 modules configuration.
    a2ensite x.conf 


systemctl reload apache2

Appears: Job for apache2.service failed.
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/x.conf
Invalid command '\xff\xfe<', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
